# Invertible Functions and averages

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Given $f(x)$ with  $x\ni [0,X]$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$.
Show that the average of $f'(x)$ with respect to $f(x)$ is greater than or equal to the average of $f'(x)$ with respect to $x$. 
Hint: there is a special inequality for this.

I have this problem I need to solve. I could really use some help. I've been staring at it for a while. I think my biggest problem is that I am not necessarily sure I understand the question. If someone would be able to explain the question/guide me in the right direction it would be really great. This question appears in my analysis course.

Comment: Still in deep thought over here, but have begun to think that this may be trying to develop a relationship between speed and velocity? Maybe..? Not sure. That's the only thing I can think of.